# glReadPixels for picking

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to make this game about picking different objects with the mouse and I'm using glReadPixels function but it's not working, it always displays as if my mouse wasn't picking anything. This is the code for picking:

```
void selectThing() {
    GLint viewport[4];
    GLubyte pixel[3] = {0};

    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

    glReadPixels(mouseX, viewport[3] - mouseY, 60, 60, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (void *)pixel);

    printf("%d %d %d\n", pixel[0], pixel[1], pixel[2]);
    if (pixel[0] == 0)
        printf("Selected");
    if (pixel[1] == 0)
        printf("Selected");
    if (pixel[2] == 0)
        printf("Selected");
    if (pixel[3] == 0)
        printf("Selected");
    else
        printf("Not selected");
```

}

and this is my MouseFunction:

```
void clickThing (int button, int state, int x, int y) {
int count= 0;
if (button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) {

        printf("Count: %d\n", count);
        count++;
        mouseX = x;
        mouseY = y;
        mode = CLIC;
    }

        else
        printf("Not selected \n");
```

}

Is there a better way of picking the objects flying around my window?

Comment: For one thing, you are trying to read an RGBA color into an array of data only large enough to hold RGB. I am surprised your compiler didn't point this out to you on this line: `if (pixel[3] == 0)`... That needs to be declared `GLubyte pixel[4] = {0};` if you don't want to overrun the array in multiple locations.

Comment: I don't quite understand your logic. You initialize the `pixel[]` values to 0, and then print out "Selected" (up to 4 times) if one of the values is 0. And if `pixel[3]` is **not** 0, you print out "Not selected". But that would actually be the case where you did read a value with alpha > 0.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I think it needs to be much bigger than `pixel[4]`, since the `glReadPixels()` call is for 60x60 pixels.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: Oh, good point. I didn't even notice that. I assumed it was 1x1 since this is for picking.